# Drawing a networkx graph in PNG to stdout / http response

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, bottle, httpserver

Networkx utilizes Matplotlib under the hood.

With Matplotlib directly, a server script that serves an image is pretty straightforward (using Bottle for simplicity):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from matplotlib.backend.backends_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from StringIO import StringIO
from bottle import route, response

@route("/plot.png")                                             
def serve_image():                                                   
    F = Figure()                              # new figure
    P = F.add_subplot(111)                    # new plot container inside the figure
    P.plot(list(range(10)), list(range(10)))  # simple plot
    PNG = StringIO()                          # container for PNG data
    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(F)               # create image
    canvas.print_png(PNG)                     # draw image into the container
    response.content_type = "image/png"       # duh
    return PNG.getvalue()                     # return contents of the container
```

However, Networkx seems to use Matplotlib *implicitly*, not creating any instances of figures or subplots. The manual usually boils down to:

```
networkx.draw(my_graph)
plot.show()
```

How does one serve this plot as a PNG image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not particularly familiar with `networkx`, but it appears to [take an `ax` kwarg](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw) that specifies the Axes object to draw on.

In your case, that would be your `P` object, returned by `fig.add_subplot`.

Typically, code that does that looks something like:

```
def blah(data, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    return ax.plot(data)
```

Therefore, the pyplot state machine is only invoked if no axes object is specified.  You should be able to use it safely in your case as long as you pass in the axes object you've manually created.

Looking at `networkx.draw`, [it appears to follow that pattern](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L111).

Comment: Wow, talk about a misnomer! I use matplotlib in a hack-it-to-do-it kind of way, never really learned it systematically -- so I would never guess that "axis" meant "plot." Thanks!

Comment: Well, just for clarification, `axis` is different than `axes` in matplotlib terms. The `Axes` instance (commonly called `ax`) is the "plot", while both the `xaxis` and `yaxis` are instances of `Axis`. Hope it helped, regardless!

Answer (score 4):

You can send a matplotlib axes instance into `networkx.draw()` (and other functions) using the `ax=` keyword.  E.g. in your case you would use

```
P = F.add_subplot(111)                   
P.plot(list(range(10)), list(range(10)))
networkx.draw(my_graph, ax=P) # draw into axis P
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Joe appears to have posted first, though, and has a bit more information, so I had to accept his answer instead.